# I used Datatable its fine on one page once i used it another page it is not work?

Tags: javascript

**"I used same code for  another grid view  it will not populate the searching and sorting is Ok pagination is also working fine but the search box is disappear" ?**

Master Page Java script and Datatables libraries
[image]

I searched alot but  i cannot find any solution .

Front End Code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>


 <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#GridView2').DataTable()
        });


    </script>


 <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" Width="1050px" >
                   <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White"></AlternatingRowStyle>
                      <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hs"   ItemStyle-CssClass="hs"  SortExpression="id"></asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="referenceNo" HeaderText="referenceNo" SortExpression="referenceNo"></asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="supplier" HeaderText="supplier" SortExpression="supplier"></asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="supplierID" HeaderText="supplierID" SortExpression="supplierID"></asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="date" HeaderText="date" SortExpression="date"></asp:BoundField>
                    </Columns>

                     <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99"></FooterStyle>

                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>

                    <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black"></PagerStyle>

                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE"></RowStyle>

                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></SelectedRowStyle>

                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2"></SortedAscendingCellStyle>

                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384"></SortedAscendingHeaderStyle>

                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3"></SortedDescendingCellStyle>

                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357"></SortedDescendingHeaderStyle>
                </asp:GridView>

                <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:IMS %>' SelectCommand="SELECT [id], [referenceNo], [supplier], [supplierID], [date] FROM [tbl_purchases]"></asp:SqlDataSource>


Backend Code :

 public static void MakeAccessible(GridView grid)
        {
            if (grid.Rows.Count <= 0) return;
            grid.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
            grid.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
            if (grid.ShowFooter)
                grid.FooterRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;
        }







        protected  void GridView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreRender(e);

            MakeAccessible(GridView2);
        }
```

Every thing i have in my code  is posted here ?

Comment: so what is the error in the console?

Comment: no console error  it should show the search box i am using jquery datatable  plugin on inspect element there is error                                     1- "uncaught typeerror : cannot read property 'mData' of undefined" 2- "unexpected identifier light.js"                                                         3- "jquery is not defined at datatable.min.js"